# AKsampler in combination with AKmicrophonetracker

Tags: audiokit

I have merged the AKsampler example and the AKmicrophone(tracker), adding the microphone in the”conductor” Class, zo MIDI io is running and it is working but....

- The volume of the sampler is reduced to about half
- I tried the mix>tracker>booster setup but got random frequencies from the tracker (high values with the correct ones spread around)
- With the AKmicrophonetracker it is working but the "getNote" algorithm of the microphone analysis example is consistent about half a note wrong

I had to raise the notefrequencytable entrys with ca 145 cents toget the notes right

My guess is its a samplerate-buffer-hop problem: anyone any suggestion? I have tried several different AKsettings and AKsessionsettings, stopping and restarting audiokit and connecting and disconnecting the nodes.